# wikipedia page: get the list of all links with their wikidata ids

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia

For a Wikipedia page: is it possible to get the list of all Wikipedia links on that page with their respective wikidata IDs in a single query/API call?

Optional: can additional information of the respective wikidata items like a property value also be received with the query?

Comment: Why don't you process the HTML page?

Comment: I was looking for an easier and "cleaner" solution, and I think using available API calls is the approach preferred by wikipedia / wikidata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be possible using the Wikipedia API.

You can get a list of all links from a certain article: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=London

You can also get information about description, alias and label from Wikidata for all links from an article: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=links&titles=London&prop=pageterms

But [there doesn't seem to be any way to get any other information from Wikidata on Wikipedia](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API#Wikibase_clients).

If you use Wikidata API, you can get all the Wikidata-related information you want, but there is no way to get the links of a Wikipedia article there.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is [possible](https://github.com/eldur/jwbf/issues/14) using MediaWiki API [generators](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=links&titles=Logic&prop=pageprops&ppprop=wikibase_item&gpllimit=500&format=json

---

See also [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11446/16193) on how to receive additional information.