# wikidata: (when) will it be possible to query for wikipedia page links?

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia

(When) will the following be possible:

- For a wikipedia page: get the list of all wikipedia links on that page with their respective wikidata IDs in a single query/API call.
- Receive additional information of the respective wikidata items like a property value with the query.

Answer (score 3):

> (When) will the following be possible:

Search in their [Phabricator](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/tag/wikidata/).

> For a wikipedia page: get the list of all wikipedia links on that page
>   with their respective wikidata IDs in a single query/API call.

To some extent, it is possible right now. There are two ways.

### 1

```
PREFIX mw: <http://tools.wmflabs.org/mw2sparql/ontology#>

SELECT ?link_to ?wikidata_item WHERE {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None"
  VALUES (?link_from) {(<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL>)}
  SERVICE <http://tools.wmflabs.org/mw2sparql/sparql> {
    ?link_from mw:internalLinkTo ?link_to .
  }
  ?link_to schema:about ?wikidata_item .
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20mw%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Ftools.wmflabs.org%2Fmw2sparql%2Fontology%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Flink_to%20%3Fwikidata_item%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20hint%3AQuery%20hint%3Aoptimizer%20%22None%22%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Flink_from%29%20%7B%28%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSPARQL%3E%29%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Ftools.wmflabs.org%2Fmw2sparql%2Fsparql%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Flink_from%20mw%3AinternalLinkTo%20%3Flink_to%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Flink_to%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fwikidata_item%20.%0A%7D)

See also:

- [MW2SPARQL](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MW2SPARQL) project description;
- [Another](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T158955) related activity.

### 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?link_to ?wikidata_item ?page_title WHERE {
  VALUES (?link_from) {(<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL>)} 
  ?link_from schema:name ?title .
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org" ;
                      wikibase:api "Generator" ;
                      mwapi:generator "links" ;
                      mwapi:titles ?title ;
                      mwapi:inprop "url" ;
                      mwapi:redirects "true" .
    ?link_to wikibase:apiOutputURI "@fullurl" .
    ?wikidata_item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
    ?page_title wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:title .
  }
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Flink_to%20%3Fwikidata_item%20%3Fpage_title%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Flink_from%29%20%7B%28%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSPARQL%3E%29%7D%20%0A%20%20%3Flink_from%20schema%3Aname%20%3Ftitle%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22en.wikipedia.org%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22Generator%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agenerator%20%22links%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Atitles%20%3Ftitle%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Ainprop%20%22url%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Aredirects%20%22true%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Flink_to%20wikibase%3AapiOutputURI%20%22%40fullurl%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwikidata_item%20wikibase%3AapiOutputItem%20mwapi%3Aitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpage_title%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20mwapi%3Atitle%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

See also:

- [MWAPI](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual/MWAPI) description.

> Receive additional information of the respective wikidata items like a
>   property value with the query.

Add regular SPARQL to the above queries, e. g.

```
FILTER (bound(?wikidata_item))
OPTIONAL {?wikidata_item wdt:P1482 ?stackexchange_tag}
```